# Eclipse Egit Synchronize Workspace No changes / Empty

Tags: eclipse, egit

I use Eclipse with Egit and when I do Syncronize with:

1. Team Synchronize Workspace
2. Team, Advanced, Synchronize (my tag)

I only get "No changes in Git" ...

I have changes/new files not yet comitted, please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deinstalled everything with git. Dragged the "Install" link on this page:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider

to Eclipse. The link itself:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=1336